# $B(\chi), L'(1,\chi)/L(1,\chi),\dotsc$

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, analytic-number-theory, l-functions

Let $\chi$ be a primitive Dirichlet character of modulus $q>1$. Write, as is customary, $B(\chi)$ for the constant in the expression
$$\frac{\Lambda'(s,\chi)}{\Lambda(s,\chi)} = B(\chi) + \sum_\rho \left(\frac{1}{s-\rho} + \frac{1}{\rho}\right),$$
where $\Lambda(s,\chi)$ is a completed Dirichlet $L$-function and $\sum_\rho$ is a sum over its zeros. Obviously,
$B(\chi) = \Lambda'(0,\chi)/\Lambda(0,\chi)$. Since
$$\frac{L'(s,\chi)}{L(s,\chi)} = \frac{\Lambda'(s,\chi)}{\Lambda(s,\chi)} - \frac{1}{2} \frac{\Gamma'((s+\kappa)/2)}{\Gamma((s+\kappa)/2)} - \frac{1}{2} \log \frac{q}{\pi},$$
where $\kappa = [\chi(-1)=-1]$, we see that $$B(\chi) = b(\chi) - \frac{\gamma}{2} - \kappa \log 2 + \frac{1}{2} \log \frac{q}{\pi},$$ where $b(\chi)$ is the constant term in the Laurent expansion of $L'(s,\chi)/L(s,\chi)$ around $s=0$. We can easily show that 
$$b(\chi) = \log \frac{2\pi}{q} + \gamma - \frac{L'(1,\overline{\chi})}{L(1,\overline{\chi})}$$ by taking logarithms on both sides of the functional equation. We thus obtain that
$$B(\chi) = \frac{1}{2} \log \frac{4^{1-\kappa} \pi}{q} + \frac{\gamma}{2} - \frac{L'(1,\overline{\chi})}{L(1,\overline{\chi})}.$$

It seems clear to me that this expression for $B(\chi)$ must be (very) classical. Now, looking in Montgomery-Vaughan for something else, I see that, in section 10.3, it states that "The constant $B(\chi)$... was long considered to be mysterious; the simple formula (10.39) for it [namely, the expression for $B(\chi)$ right here] is due to Vorhauer (2006)." Here Vorhauer (2006) is an unpublished preprint (not accessible online). I'd gladly give credit where credit is due, but I can't help thinking that this expression must have been known long before 2006. Does anybody have an earlier reference?

(And what would be so mysterious about $B(\chi)$? IMHO, it  is just tricky for the same reason that $L'(1,\chi)/L(1,\chi)$, viz., the possibility of a Siegel zero. Or is it just that we don't have an expression for it as nice as the class number formula? (Do we? EDIT: for $\chi$ odd, we do; see Prop. 10.3.5 (due to...?) in Henri Cohen's Number Theory.) On the issue of bounding it, see [$|L'(1,\chi)/L(1,\chi)|$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/337265/l1-chi-l1-chi?rq=1]).)

Comment: I'm not sure I would agree that $B(\chi)$ was "mysterious", as much as a minor role-player. See page 83 of Davenport, where he says it "can be expressed in terms of the expansion of $L'/L$ in powers of $s$, but it seems to be very difficult to estimate $B(\chi)$ at all satisfactorily as a function of $q$", parenthetically adding that it usually gets eliminated by subtraction in subsequent arguments. Later on the page he says "The difficulty in estimating $B(\chi)$ is connected with the fact that, as far as we know, $L(s,\chi)$ may have a zero near to $s=0$."

Comment: Yes, I don't see the mystery either. There's a difficulty, but it's exactly the same one as for $L(1,\chi)$ or $L'(1,\chi)/L(1,\chi)$.

Comment: So what is your question now ?

Comment: Well, I need a reference for the expression for $B(\chi)$ above other than (older than) Vorhauer. One must exist - in fact I am willing to bet that it was written down at some point in the first third of the twentieth century.

Comment: Ah well: page 83 in Davenport says clearly that $B(\chi) = - \Lambda'(1,\overline{\chi})/\Lambda(1,\overline{\chi})$ (to use the notation above), and expressing $\Lambda'(1,\overline{\chi})/\Lambda(1,\overline{\chi})$ in terms of $L'(1,\overline{\chi})/L(1,\overline{\chi})$ is trivial (indeed it's done at the top of page 83). So this is indeed classical.

Comment: Now I have another question. What is a good graduate-level textbook or general monograph older than (multiplicative) Davenport but more recent than Landau's Primzahlen? That would help settle questions in the future on what was or wasn't common knowledge at a certain point.

Comment: Prachar's Primzahlverteilung was about 10 years before Davenport.

Comment: Thanks Lucía! That still leaves almost half a century in between...

Comment: @HAHelfgott: I don't believe your conclusion that the formula is classical is correct. See the edit to my answer.

Comment: @GregMartin - see my reply below.

Comment: Just to end the discussion: the formula appears, both in terms of $\Lambda'/\Lambda$ and in terms of $L'/L$, in Landau, "Über einige ältere Vermutungen und Behauptungen in der
Primzahltheorie. II.", Math. Z., 1:213–219, *1918*, page 216, in the case $q=4$ (which is the case that Landau needed in that paper). The proof for arbitrary $q$ is the same.

Comment: Another text in the interim is Chudakov's 1947 book, Introduction to the theory of Dirichlet $L$-functions. (I had checked Landau's _Handbuch_, but found nothing, and also thought of Prachar but couldn't easily check it).

Comment: Another example (postdating Davenport, but from a slightly different tradition) is Karatsuba's _Basic Analytic Number Theory_, page 117 (Thm 12) in the translation, clearly giving $B(\chi)$ as $-(\xi'/\xi)(1,\bar\chi)$. Again it doesn't separate this as its own observation, but proceeds over zeros. http://books.google.com/books?id=WO_uCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA117&dq=karatsuba+basic+analytic+number+theory+theorem+12+with+the+same+notation&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi9r7_z5Y_lAhX38HMBHUl-DvgQ6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=karatsuba%20basic%20analytic%20number%20theory%20theorem%2012%20with%20the%20same%20notation&f=false

Comment: I think Vorhauer's true result (never published apart from the exercises section in Montgomery and Vaughan's book) was the lower bound $-\mathrm{Re}(B(\chi)) \geq \log(q)/6$ on this number. That means that the $\sum_{\rho} \mathrm{Re}{1/\rho} \gg \log{q}$ (not too small). Anyway her coefficient $1/6$ was superseded by Badzyan to the larger $1/2\sqrt{5}$ (*The Euler-Kronecker constant*, Math. Notes, vol. 87, 2010), using Stechkin's idea.

Comment: @VesselinDimitrov I see no such bound in Badzyan's paper (at http://mi.mathnet.ru/mz4736).  The Euler-Kronecker constant of a number field is not directly connected to a logarithmic derivative of the $L$-function of one Dirichlet character except in the case of a quadratic character.  The Euler--Kronecker constant for the $m$th cyclotomic field is related to a sum of logarithmic derivatives of $L$-functions of the characters mod $m$, not to the logarithmic derivative of the $L$-function of just one character, unless the cyclotomic field is quadratic.

Comment: @KConrad: Thanks for pointing this out! Yes, for quadratic characters it follows straightaway from Badzyan's bound for the Euler-Kronecker constant of the quadratic field. (But even in that case it seems that his coefficient would be the best available, as far as I was aware? Anyway I was viewing the quadratic characters as the most interesting case.) While Badzyan in that paper focuses on the Euler-Kronecker constants of global fields, but impression was that his argument based on Lemma 1 applied implicitly to arbitrary Dirichlet characters, based on the positivity of $\zeta(s)L(s,\chi)$.

Comment: @KConrad: I looked at it more carefully, and I think it works actually directly to the function $L(s,\chi)$, replacing his $\zeta_K(s)$. (No zeta factor or positivity property is relevant in Badzyan's argument.) On page 34, he estimates his $Z_K(s) = - \zeta_K'(s) / \zeta_K(s)$ from above by $-n\zeta'(s)/\zeta(s)$, for all real $s > 1$, and applies it for his choice $s = (\sqrt{5}+1)/2$. In our case we simply have to note $-\mathrm{Re}(L'(s,\chi) / L(s,\chi)) \leq -\zeta'(s) / \zeta(s)$, for all real $s > 1$, and the argument goes through verbatim (choice $s$ = the Golden Mean, for Lemma 1).

Comment: So my comment was mostly methodological, about the specific saving coefficient of $1/2\sqrt{5}$ coming out of this method. In a way this goes back all the way to Stechkin's work [3] on $\zeta(s)$ that he cited (cf. the estimate (19) there). BTW: I was wondering if perhaps one manifestation of the analytic difficulties inherent in Vinogradov's conjecture is that it is closely related to the lower bound $(L'/L)(1,\chi_q) > -\varepsilon\log(q)$, (once $q \gg_{\varepsilon} 1$), but for sufficiently general L-functions including $\zeta_K(s)$, Badzyan's result does become sharp up to the constant.

Comment: @KConrad: By the same token, Vorhauer's argument sketched in the exercises section of Montgomery and Vaughan's book applies to $\zeta_K(s)$ to yield the weaker inequality $\gamma_K > - (2/3)\log{\sqrt{|D_{K/\mathbb{Q}}|}}$, in lieu of Badzyan's coefficient $1-1/\sqrt{5}$ that still appears to be the best unconditional one available. It does seem like a kind of threshold exponent in the present day theory, although it does improve under GRH to $0.459$, as Badzyan also showed in that paper. For bounded degree fields, or Dirichlet $L$-function, it should improve to any $\varepsilon > 0$...

Comment: ..but without the GRH, that seems essentially as hard as the Vinogradov conjecture on the least quadratic non-residue.

Answer (score 5):

I am replying to this question “for  odd, we do; see Prop. 10.3.5 (due to...?) in Henri Cohen's Number Theory”. I would be happy to insert a comment instead, but my MO-reputation is not good enough...

In a paper published in 1989, Kanemitsu wrote that this formula was first published by Berger in 1883.

Kanemitsu’s paper is entitled “ On evaluation of certain limits in closed form”, pages 459-474, of the volume:
Proceedings of the International Number Theory Conference held at Université Laval, July 5-18, 1987
Ed. by Koninck, Jean M. de / Levesque, Claude
Series:De Gruyter Proceedings in Mathematics.

Berger’s paper is “sur une sommation des quelques series”, Nova Acta Reg. Soc. Sci. Ups.(3) 12 (1883).

Answer (score 1):

When I was a graduate student at the University of Michigan (this would be the mid-1990s), I took an analytic number theory class from Montgomery, from notes that would eventually become his book with Vaughan. I remember learning directly from Montgomery in that class that the real part of $B(\chi)$ could be written in terms of the zeros of $L(s,\chi)$, but that the imaginary part was indeed mysterious.

Perhaps part of our mental block as a discipline was that the usual formula for $\Re B(\chi)$ contained the term $\Re \dfrac{L'}L(1,\chi)$, while Vorhauer's formula for $B(\chi)$ turns out to contain the term $\dfrac{L'}L(1,\overline\chi)$ rather than $\dfrac{L'}L(1,\chi)$. (Note that the formula in your post contains an omission in this regard.)

In any case, given the timing of this information, and the fact that Montgomery is a central figure in classical analytic number theory who is also dedicated to knowing its literature, I am confident that the formula in question is indeed due to Ulrike Vorhauer as noted. I think the correct thing to do is to credit Vorhauer with the formula's discovery and cite the book of Montgomery and Vaughan as the best source we have.

*Edited to add*: I have checked Davenport's book, and the formula it gives for $B(\chi)$ at the top of page 83 is not the same as Vorhauer's formula (an infinite sum over zeros is still present in Davenport's formula). The quote "can be expressed in terms of the expansion of $L'/L$ in powers of $s$" does not at all imply that Vorhauer's formula was known (for instance, it gives no hint that the distinction between $\chi$ and $\bar\chi$ is relevant); it corresponds only to one of the very first steps in the sketch from the OP. Moreover, Montgomery himself revised Davenport's book; it strains credulity that he, having carefully read page 83 of Davenport, would attribute the formula to someone other than Davenport if that page were a sufficient source for the formula.

It's one thing to say that Davenport and those who preceded him *could* have derived the formula (that much seems clear). But what evidence we do have points to the conclusion that nobody *actually* derived Vorhauer's formula until she did. That sort of thing happens all the time. We still give credit to the actual discoverers (Vorhauer, in this case); we don't deem the result "classical" based on our feeling.

*Edit 2*: Apparently Vorhauer's paper was accepted to Acta Arithmetica, but the publication process stalled at the page-proofs stage.

Comment: Thanks for the anecdote. Unfortunately the two Montgomeries are one and the same, so all that this shows is that (surprisingly) Montgomery had a mental block. Happens to us all. My (educated, I hope) guess would be that Vorhauer's paper was never published because a referee stated that the equality was completely classical. It is indeed an immediate consequence of the functional equation.

Comment: Of course one possibility is to write to Vorhauer.

Comment: - and you are right about the typo (the conjugation comes from applying the functional equation).

Comment: Just wrote - we'll see.

Comment: @H A Helfgott: Interesting. Please let us know, what Vorhauer says, if she replies.

Comment: As pointed out by MyNinthAccount above, p. 83 in Davenport gives an answer: it states clearly that $B(\chi) = -\Lambda'(1,\overline{\chi})/\Lambda(1,\overline{\chi})$ (well, he uses $\xi$ to denote what I call $\Lambda$, but that's literally the only difference). Of course one can write out $\Lambda'(1,\overline{\chi})/\Lambda(1,\overline{\chi})$ plus two terms (indeed Davenport implicitly does that at the top of 83), so it's all classical after all. Weird.

Comment: For those who don't know, Montgomery and Vorhauer had a child together in 2004 or so, and broke up a few years later. I'm not too sure she particularly wants to revisit this episode...

Comment: Well, the issue seems now fairly clear, so, if I don't get an answer, I won't insist.

Comment: Edited to clarify that the evidence from Davenport does not actually suggest that the formula was discovered before Vorhauer.

Comment: Greg Martin: as I say in the comments above, Davenport stated very clearly that $B(\chi) = - \xi'(1,\overline{\chi})/\xi(1,\overline{\chi})$ (yes, with a complex conjugate character $\overline{\chi}$), where $\xi$ is the completed L-function. I agree it strains credulity, but it is right there, in Page 83.

Comment: You're conflating two different parts of the page. The quote about "the expansion of $L'/L$" does not mention $\overline\chi$. The line you do mention is in the middle of an argument that proceeds from there directly to the real part of the quantity (and back to $\chi$). I stand by my answer: there is no evidence here that Davenport knew Vorhauer's formula.

Comment: Because "the expansion of $L'/L$" means something else, namely, that you can express $B(\chi)$ in terms of the constant term $b(\chi)$ of $L(s,\chi)$ at $s=0$. Yes, Davenport actually uses the formula $B(\chi) = -\xi'(1,\overline{\chi})/\xi(1,\overline{\chi})$ for another, related purpose; so what? It is right there. Just to drive home the point: it involves $\overline{\chi}$ -- which you pointed out as crucial.

Comment: There are two questions here: (a) whether an expression of $B(\chi)$ in terms of $\Lambda'(1,\overline{\chi})/\Lambda(1,\overline{\chi})$, or $L'(1,\overline{\chi})/L(1,\overline{\chi})$ was known (it was; it is in the middle of the page in a standard reference); (b) why Montgomery and at least part of his immediate circle ever thought that there was any mystery. I agree that question (b) is baffling, but it does not concern me here.

Comment: (All I can say on (b) is that Davenport's correct remarks on the difficulty of estimating $B(\chi)$ in terms of $q$ (of course there is an essential difficulty: there may be a Siegel zero) may have given some the wrong impression.)